# Compress large log file before reading

Tags: c#, performance, compression

We have a large amount of logs (117 logs with total of about 17gb of data). It's straight text so I know it will compress well. I'm not looking for great compression, or speed (but that would be a good bonus). What I currently do is get a list of log files to read (they have a date stamp in the file name, so I filter on that first). After I get the list I then read each file using `File.ReadAllLines()` but we also filter on that...

```
private void GetBulkUpdateItems(List<string> allLines, Regex updatedRowsRegEx)
{
    foreach (var file in this)
        allLines.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(file).Where(x => updatedRowsRegEx.IsMatch(x)));

    allLines.Sort();
}
```

reading 5 files from the network takes about 22 seconds. What I'd like to do is compress the list of files into a single zip file. copy the zip file locally, then unzip them and do the rest. Problem is I can't figure out how to start. Since I'm using .net 4.5 I first tried `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` but it wants a Directory and I don't want all 117 files. I saw someone use a network stream and 7zip which sounded promising, and I'm fairly certain that 7zip is installed on the server I need the logs from (Probably not important because we use the UNC path). So I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try ZipFileExtensions.CreateEntryFromFile. Details available here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485724%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @PraveenPaulose I gave what you suggested a shot. it appeared to work ok for a 17 meg log file, but then I tried it on the largest file I had (670mb) and it through a out of memory exception. Talked it over some and I think what we will do is zip the logs up with a different program that already runs on that same server. Then this program can just copy the zipped file and do what it needs to do from their.

Comment: If that is an option, you might as well do that. Will save coding time and effort :)

Answer (score 0):

[ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the underlying class for `ZipFile` and allows more granular manipulation.

Sample from the article adding hardcoded text:

```
using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(
           @"c:\users\exampleuser\release.zip", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry("Readme.txt");
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
        {
                writer.WriteLine("Information about this package.");
                writer.WriteLine("========================");
        }
    }
}
```

As [Praveen Paulose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2961675/praveen-paulose) suggested you can use [ZipFileExtensions.CreateEntryFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485724%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create entry from file to add to archive.

Comment: See my comment above. Basically this solution doesn't work because with really large files I run out of memory. I could take the time to buffer it and break it into smaller chunks... or our solution was to use a program that is already deployed on the server to archive the logs.

Comment: @RobertSnyder I'm sort of surprised that `ZipArchive` and `Stream.CopyTo` uses a lot of memory (but I have not tried to pack huge files myself, so very well could happen). Indeed running external program would be simpler with basic `Process.Start` and passing list of files to compress to the program you use.

Comment: I don't even have to use process start. the program is a scheduled task and it checks the "last write time" of a file. If it is x days old then it purges it. Purge consists of compressing the file to a zip, then deleting the original. The file names have a date stamp in them so I just filter the files according to that.

Comment: @RobertSnyder did not realized that you are looking for non-C# solution. Indeed using existing tools is generally better approach.

Comment: I was looking for a C# solution.  I would have preferred it really. And technically it still is a C# solution (the file purger is a program we wrote in C# that is called from windows task scheduler)